# Automatically update a RelatedProperty when adding a new entity to the collection in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many, crud

EntityFramework 5.0

Suppose I have the following setup:

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("Books")]
    [Required]
    public Author Author {get; set;}
}

public class Author
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books {get; set;}
}
```

Then in my code I create a new Book and I do this:

```
author.Books.Add(newBook);
```

How can I have the Book pick-up its Author automatically instead of having to write this every time:

```
newBook.Author = author;
```

I want the child entity to pick up its parent automatically when added to the parent's collection.

Is this possible? Fluent mapping maybe?

Or do I have to maintain both sides of this bi-directional relationship myself?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.

This is the default behavior and the book gets its Author out-of-the-box.

Case closed.